# How can I update the all the views inside a TabHost when pressing on a ContextMenu item from within one of the views?

Tags: android

I am implementing a music player application in Android. My play list selection screen is implemented as a tab selector widget which contains a ListActivity inside each of the tabs: Artist, Albums, Songs.
I want to update the ListView in each of the ListActivity when I delete an item from any of the lists.

i.e. When I long press an item in the Artists list a context menu is drawn with "Delete Artist"
And it should delete all the songs from this artist in the Songs ListView, delete all the albums by this artist in the Albums ListView, and finally delete the entry for the artist in the Artist ListView.

Each of the ListActivity has its own fillData() method, which updates the ListView when the button in the context menu is pressed.

How can I call the fillData() method of the Albums ListActivity after I update the ListView inside of the Artists ListActivity?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have the delete action broadcast a Update message

```
public static final String REFRESH_DATA = "package.music.REFRESH_DATA";

Intent myintent = new Intent(REFRESH_DATA);
myintent.putExtra("type","REFRESH_DATA");                
sendBroadcast(myintent);
```

and then in the Activities inside the tabs have

```
private BroadcastReceiver mRefreshDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        setData();
    }
};
```

(remember to register it onCreate() and to deregisterit on destroy

Comment: I just solved it by overriding the onResume() method of each ListActivity, calling fillData() inside of it. This is inefficient since the ListView will be refreshed every single time regardless of deletions. It works because onResume() is called when you select a tab. I will convert the code to use the BroadCastReceiver, I am relatively new to Android and didn't know how to use these to trigger events to other activities in the application.  Thanks again.